# How to prevent form submission using the keyboard (esp. the space key)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I have a web application where on one specific screen I have to make sure the user clicked the button using the mouse as opposed to just pressing enter or space.

I have written this code:

```
$('button').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 10 || e.which === 13 || e.which === 32) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, this only works for enter. The form can still be submitted by pressing space on a button. I am just wondering what caused this inconsistency and how to get around it?

Edit:

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/billccn/3JmtY/1/. Check the second check box and pressing enter while the focus is on the button will have no effect. If I further disable the input and expand the keydown trapping to the whole form, then enter cannot be used to submit the form.

Edit 2:

I do have a backup plan which is replacing the button with a link or even a plain div and use the click event to submit the form programmatically. However, extra work is required to make it look like a button so I'd rather use a button is possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? It'd be great if you can put an example of the actual incorrect behavior

Comment: The space-bar is returning `32` but your jsFiddle code is looking for `23`... a typo?

Comment: @Sparky Yes, it is a typo. I have updated the fiddle. You can still use the spacebar to "click" the button though. The effect seems to be exactly the same as a mouse click in the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out: handling space (32) on `keyup` will prevent the click event.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3JmtY/2/

Answer (score 0):

Missed the Point of your Question. After some googleing if found the following trick:

Bind the `keypress` event to your from and listen to it's keycode. If the keycode is `13`
 (enter), prevent all default actions  (`event.preventDefaul()`) and prevent further event bubbeling ( `return false;` ).

Her is a fiddler code example:

HTML:

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
    <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">Trigger the handler</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#target').keypress(function (event) {
    var code = event.keyCode || event.which; 
  if (code  == 13) {               
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});

$('#target').submit(function (event, data2) {
    debugger;
    alert('test');
    return false;
});
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/ggTDs/

Note that the form is not submited when enter is clicked!

Comment: Not sure if you read through my question. I still want the form to be submittable, just not by a key press. Clicking the button using the mouse should work as usual.

Comment: Missed the Point of your Question. After some googleing if found the following trick and corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. 13 for Enter key and 32 for Spacebar.

```
$("#form_id").on('keydown keyup keypress', function( e ) {

    if ( e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13 || e.which == 32 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```